# Getting value of $\sin A \sin B$

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

my solution
[image]

I am able to get the answer. When i am trying to evaluate 
Sin A Sin B , i am not clear how to approach?
I feel data is insufficeint to discredit option D

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\tan A\tan B = 2\implies \sin A \sin B= 2\cos A\cos B$$
and
$$ \cos(A-B) = \cos A\cos B+\sin A \sin B ={3\over 5}$$

we get $$\cos A\cos B ={1\over 5}\implies \sin A \sin B = {2\over 5}$$

Comment: @maveric I see you are not aceppting the answers you get. You should do that. That is a pratice here, the whole pint of this site.

Comment: what you answered i dint require.

Comment: @maveric You should decide wether you will downvote or upvote or notihng. Don't change all the time.

Comment: see, i am new to this. So when i read your comment sir, i felt that your solution was the one which i had already solved. I dint require it.so i downvoted it. then i got second thoughts that you had attemptef so i upvoted. sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1):

Given:

$$C_aC_b+S_aS_b=\frac35,$$
$$S_aS_b=2\,CaCb.$$

a) $3\,C_aC_b=\dfrac35$;

b) $S_aS_b=2\,CaCb$;

c) $\cos(a+b)=C_aC_b-S_aS_b=\dfrac15-\dfrac25$;

d) $\sin(a-b)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(a-b)}=\pm\dfrac45,
\\\sin(a+b)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(a+b)}=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{24}}5,
\\2S_aC_b=\sin(a-b)+\sin(a+b)=\dfrac{\pm4\pm\sqrt{24}}5.$

Comment: why is question being downvoted?